# Material-UI components overflows screen only on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

**Edit**: This is the only page with problems. Other pages of the same website display correctly.

I've made a web page with React and Material-UI. The top components are `Grid` and `Container`. It looks good in desktop, but in mobile.. well.. this is the side of the screen:

[image]

There's extra space created (light grey) and the Pictures and cards venture outside the screen max width. The header (blue) and the background (light blue) have the correct width (the width of the screen).

i'm using `Grid` and `Container`.

This is the root component that contains the cards:

```
<Grid
  container
  spacing={0}
  direction="row"
  justify="space-around"
  alignItems="center"
  style={{ minHeight: "20vh" }}
> ....
```

This is another container that scapes the width:

```
<Container maxWidth="lg" style={{ marginBottom: "5vh" }}>
  <Paper style={{ padding: 20 }}>
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={0}
      direction="column"
      justify="flex-start"
      alignItems="center"
    > ....
```

The Header that displays correctly it's just an `AppBar`.

The image at the top that overflows returns:

```
<div className={classes.heroContent}>
  <Container maxWidth="md" align="center">
    <Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      justify="flex-end"
      alignItems="center"
    > ...
```

And the `classes.heroContent` is:

```
 heroContent: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${grupo})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 8),
    minHeight: "20vh",
  }, ...
```

What could be the reason of this overflow thing? I've been reading the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) and I can't find the bug.

Comment: Did you set a mobile viewport meta?

Comment: Yes I did. Some components overflow at this page, but the rest of the pages display correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve solve it. There where two problems.

**Problem 1:**

One grid component that was the root component of the cards was designated as `container` but not as `item`.

**Explanation of problem 1:**

As the cards are inside the `Grid` of the parent component, there are also an `item`. After I designated all `Grid` components that had at least one `Grid` inside as a `container`, and all the `Grid` that where inside a `Grid` container directly or indirectly as a parent component as `item` it almost worked.

**Problem 2:**

The combination of media sizes inside the cards and margins of the cards where too big for the screen. The solution is to change the `margin` and `width` units.

**Explanation problem 2:**

the cards have this  css now:

```
cards: {
    margin: "5vw",
    marginBottom: "0vh",
  },
  media: {
    height: "35vh",
    width: "45vw",
  },
```

The problem was the units. I was using `margin: '5vh'` so the margins where calculated according to the height of the vierport. In viewports with bigger heights than widths (mobile) a fraction of the height was still bigger than the width.